# Problems with table calls in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I am writing a mathematical model, and after writing and connecting the components, I need to set the table of initial data values to make the model easier to understand, but when using record, I encountered some problems.
Below is the code for the table I wrote

```
package initialnumber

  record constantnumber
    parameter  Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature Tair=10+273.15
                                                "环境温度";
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate W0_8=632207/3600
      "设计工况下第八级组入口蒸汽流量";
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Diameter Din=0.024 "管内径";
  end constantnumber;

  record startnumber
    Modelica.Units.SI.Mass Ms(start=195)
                                        "蒸汽质量";
    Modelica.Units.SI.Mass Ml(start=91000)
                                          "水质量";
  end startnumber;
end initialnumber;
```

What I want to achieve is to keep a table in the overall visual interface where the initial data of all components can be modified.As shown in the figure below
[image]
The simple code for the above image is as follows

```
block A_03
  A_QT a_QT annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{98,30},{118,50}})));
  Deaerator.dea deaerator;
  initialnumber.constantnumber constantnumber(N=130)
  initialnumber.startnumber startnumber
equation 
   connect(a_IP2_1.IP2_smallturbine, a_smallturbine.smallturbine_rukou)
 connect(a_nqq.shushui, LP7.outlet2);
 connect(a_IP2_1.IP2_CQ, deaerator.Dea_CQ);
end A_03;
```

But at present, I can't modify the component's data in the above interface, and the component data has not changed after changing the initial value.
In the various parts, I also called the table, as shown below
[image]

I would like to know how to change the initial value of the part by simply changing the data in the table after the visualization (as in the first image), thank you in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to answer, as I don't fully understand the question. To my understanding these are two different issues:

1. Setting a start-value via the `start` attribute: When only settings `v1(start=23)`, the value 23 will only be used as a start value for a potential iteration of `v1`. To really set it as an initial value for the simulation, you need to set `v1(start=23, fixed=true)`. This could be the reason that your start values are not set the way you expect it.
2. Using a parameter from the record should be possible using the dot-notation. So e.g. for a temperature, that would be `T(start=constantnumber.Tair, fixed=true)`.

Hoping that helps...

Comment: You can simply understand how I put a table in two models, and how I change the table in one model and make the data in the other model change as well

Comment: If there are two separate models they are not able to access each others values. If you want to change data in a single place, I would try to create data-records which contain the data. Then you can access these records in any model...